# How use the function NOW() in PHP

Tags: php, sql, datetime-format

I have a temporary table SQL. I have a filed that give me the name of the user that modified any information by `get_current_user`.
I added another field `type=DATETIME` to recovre the date and the hour of the user modifcation.

In `PHP`I added it like all my function, but it got an error.
The code is the following:

```
         $sql = "INSERT INTO  `...`.`correspondants_bis` 
    (`code_client` , `name`, `surname` ,`phone`, `fax`, `email`, `added_by`, `Date`, `condition`)

        VALUES ('" . $correspondent->getCodeClient() . "',
     '" . str_replace("'", "''", $correspondent->getName()) . "',
     '" . str_replace("'", "''", $correspondent->getSurname()) . "',
     '" . $correspondent->getPhone() . "', 
    '" . $correspondent->getFax() . "',
     '" . $correspondent->getEmail() . "', 
    '" . $user . "','" . NOW() . "',
    '1'
        );";
```

the error is:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function..... 
Attempted to call function "NOW" from namespace....
```

I know that NOW() is an `SQL function`, just I got you an example of `insert` because I don't know how I add it, and this following my `select function`:

```
 public function getCorrespondentByIdBis($id) {
        $statement = "SELECT * FROM `correspondants_bis` WHERE `id`='" . $id . "'";
        $result = $this->_db->query($statement);
        while ($data = $result->fetch()) {
            $correspondent = new CorrespondentBis($data['id'], $data['code_client'], $data['name'], $data['surname'], $data['phone'], $data['fax'], $data['email'], get_current_user(), NOW(), 0);
        }
       }
return $correspondent;
}
```

Can you tell me please, how I can change my code to resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

now is not php function so replace

```
NOW()
```

to

```
date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
```

so your final code

```
$correspondent = new CorrespondentBis($data['id'], $data['code_client'], $data['name'], $data['surname'], $data['phone'], $data['fax'], $data['email'], get_current_user(), date('Y-m-d H:i:s'), 0);
```

2.no need to use quote , just use `NOW()`
so your final query

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO  `...`.`correspondants_bis` 
     (`code_client` , `name`, `surname` ,`phone`, `fax`, `email`, `added_by`, `Date`, `condition`)

     VALUES ('" . $correspondent->getCodeClient() . "',
     '" . str_replace("'", "''", $correspondent->getName()) . "',
     '" . str_replace("'", "''", $correspondent->getSurname()) . "',
     '" . $correspondent->getPhone() . "', 
     '" . $correspondent->getFax() . "',
     '" . $correspondent->getEmail() . "', 
     '" . $user . "',
      NOW(),
     '1'
      );";
```

for more information

http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-now/

Answer (score 1):

`NOW()` is a SQL function, so you don't need it in PHP:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO  `...`.`correspondants_bis` 
    (`code_client` , `name`, `surname` ,`phone`, `fax`, `email`, `added_by`, `Date`, `condition`)

        VALUES ('" . $correspondent->getCodeClient() . "',
     '" . str_replace("'", "''", $correspondent->getName()) . "',
     '" . str_replace("'", "''", $correspondent->getSurname()) . "',
     '" . $correspondent->getPhone() . "', 
    '" . $correspondent->getFax() . "',
     '" . $correspondent->getEmail() . "', 
    '" . $user . "',NOW(),
    '1'
        );";
```

Sidenote: Building your SQL statements in this way, makes you susceptible to SQL injections. Better use prepared statements.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works very well. I was need just to delete the quotes.